# Import ReactJS component to typescript component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Background: I am working on an existing project that already has a few components available or created in ReactJS. Recently, we have decided to migrate to TypeScript with React. Right now, I am trying to figure out how I can import existing components into new typescript components. [This blog](https://wanago.io/2021/04/12/react-components-in-javascript-typescript-code/) helped me figure out how to do it. But I am not able to make it work for some components available in my project.

Note: the code blocks given below is to explain the context and it is now how we are using it.

Below ReactJS component already exist in project, file name: SelectOption.js

```
function SelectOption({
  list,
  defaultValue,
  placeholder,
  inputName,
  testid,
  isRequired,
  propertyID,
  propertyName,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label
        htmlFor={`${testid}.id`}
        slot='label'
        className={Styles.label_padding}
      >
        {Resources.TIME_OFF.BATCH_ACTIONS_WORLKFLOW_APP.TIME_OFF_TYPE}
      </label>
      <select
        id={`${testid}.id`}
        name={inputName}
      >
        <option  value=''>
          {placeholder}
        </option>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <option
            value={item[propertyID]}
            key={item[propertyID]}
          >
            {item[propertyName]}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export { SelectOption };
```

I have created below declaration file to make it type compatible and to import it to new typescript component, file name: SelectOption.d.ts

```
type listItem = { ID: number; Name: string };

type listItems = listItem[];
function SelectOption({
  list: listItems,
  defaultValue: number,
  placeholder: string,
  inputName: string,
  testid: string,
  isRequired: boolean,
  propertyID: string,
  propertyName: string
}): JSX.Element;

export {SelectOption};
```

Below is the new Typescript component

```
import { SelectOption } from '../../shared/components/SelectOption/SelectOption'

export function NewTypeScriptComponent() {
    const listItems: Array<{ ID: number; Name: string }> = [
        { ID: 0, Name: 'Available' },
        { ID: 1, Name: 'Ready' },
        { ID: 2, Name: 'Started' },
    ];
    return (
        <section>
            <div>
                <SelectOption
                    list={listItems}
                    defaultValue={0}
                    placeholder={'type'}
                    inputName={''}
                    testid={true}
                    isRequired={true}
                    propertyID='ID'
                    propertyName='Name'
                />
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

Functionality is working fine. I can see the dropdown is correctly listing the given values in new component but it is given an error as shown in below screenshot

[image]

If I comment/remove first parameter(list) then same error will show for second param(defaultValue)

Any help would really appreciated to understand what I am doing wrong here.
One more question: is this a good solution to import ReactJS components into typescript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `list={listItems}` to `list={listItems as any}`

Comment: maybe you must to change list in SelectOption to be list: listItems | any;

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen, HibaYoussef As I mentioned in the question, "If I comment or remove the first parameter (list), then the same error will show for the second parameter (default value)." It is just not with list parameter; if I remove or comment the list param, even the second parameter will show the message. My worry about adding "any" to all parameters is that it will take out the benefit of typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this but I tried this out locally and it looks you are defining the function type incorrect. Change:

```
function SelectOption({
  list: listItems,
  defaultValue: number,
  placeholder: string,
  inputName: string,
  testid: string,
  isRequired: boolean,
  propertyID: string,
  propertyName: string
}): JSX.Element;
```

To:

```
function SelectOption(props: {
  list: listItems;
  defaultValue: number;
  placeholder: string;
  inputName: string;
  testid: string;
  isRequired: boolean;
  propertyID: string;
  propertyName: string;
}): JSX.Element;
```

This worked for me. In your version you are setting the type as the variable name. Adding props: {... in front gives the parameter for the component a name.